# How to access variable from one class to another in Django - Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, post

I am new to Django. In my case , I do have 2 class based views in my `views.py` which inherits API View in it . In my class 1 , i do have a dictionary inside a `POST` method.

```
class LDAPCheck(APIView):
   var 
   def post(self,request):
         var = {}
         var = "some vale"
```

Now i wanted to access the **var** in another class with extends the ApiView

```
class Submit(APIView):
     # access variable form LDAPCheck class
```

How to do this
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't.  That's why it's called a local variable.

Comment: So what changes should i do to access it ?

Comment: There is as yet insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

Comment: can you try **global var**

Comment: @wim so you reckon this one will be answered after the heat death of the universe?

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways that i can think of to do this.

1. First is you define a variable in settings.py and modify that variable.

Note: Very Dangerous, Race Conditions and values get's lost post restart.

2. Use django cache ( Pros and cons same as above mentioned but cleaner handling).
3. Use a centralized cache or redis to set and update values to be used in one or another view. This is safer, adds a new component to your system. will work across servers, restart doesn't effect.